# What is the difference between "dream" and "ambition"?

Tags: differences, nouns

I don't understand how *dream* differs from *ambition* in the following quote:

> I don't feel like summing up my ambition as just a dream, but I do have an ambition. The ambition to restore my clan and to kill a certain man without fail.

Comment: Micheal, if you don't want this question closed, I'd suggest that you make an edit, and add the definitions of _dream_ and _ambition_ (paste them from an online dictionary, just so we all know that you've at least looked them up), and then explain a little more about _why_ you're still confused, and having trouble differentiating them.

Comment: I agree with J.R.  Also, any distinction between the two should address "I have a dream.." MLK, which he did not "idly pursue."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ambition* usually refers to somebody having a desire — a much stronger feeling than a *dream*. A *dream* is something that we can idly pursue, without taking any steps to achieve it.

> - I have the ambition to become a doctor.
> - I have a dream that one day all people will have enough to eat.

Comment: In fact, the usual phrasing is "My ambition is to...", which makes the difference especially apparent.